# 2 questions regarding Implementation of org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonTypeResolver

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, jackson, spring-kafka

Im trying to implement this resolve method for Kafka's JsonTypeResolver.  However I have run into 2 issues.

How do I register my class so that kafka will use it when deserializing?

How do I use JavaType class to specify the class I want this deserialized into?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Headers;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonTypeResolver;
    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
    
public class OgTestConsumerResolver implements JsonTypeResolver {
        @Override
        public JavaType resolveType(String topic, byte[] data, Headers headers) {
            if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(topic) && topic.equals("og.test.event.with.domain.object")) {
                return new JavaTyp
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to get the functionality we wanted by:

setting the TYPE_ID_MAPPINGS mappings on the consumer properties

```
    // format is similar to JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS - comma separated list of key:value
    // for each pair, key is type id used by message producer, value is type id used by message consumer
    props.put(KafkaCustomJsonDeserializer.TYPE_ID_MAPPINGS, kp.getConsumerTypeMappings());
```

this is a string,string map with class from and class to

then extending the kafka deserializer like so

```
public class KafkaCustomJsonDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {
    public static final String TYPE_ID_MAPPINGS = "com.test.kafka.typeid.mappings";
    private static final String TYPE_ID_HEADER = "__TypeId__";
    private Map<String, String> typeIdMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        if (!isKey) {
            typeIdMap = (Map<String, String>) configs.get(TYPE_ID_MAPPINGS);
        }

        super.configure(configs, isKey);
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data) {
        Headers customHeaders = null;
        // replace type id header if replacement is configured
        if (!typeIdMap.isEmpty()) {
            if (headers != null) {
                Iterable<Header> iterable = headers.headers(TYPE_ID_HEADER);
                if (iterable != null) {
                    byte[] value = null;
                    for (Header header : iterable) {
                        value = header.value();
                        // should be only one type id header
                        break;
                    }

                    if (value != null) {
                        try {
                            String typeId = new String(value, "UTF-8");
                            String customTypeId = typeIdMap.get(typeId);
                            if (customTypeId != null) {
                                customHeaders = new RecordHeaders(headers.toArray());
                                customHeaders.remove(TYPE_ID_HEADER);
                                customHeaders.add(TYPE_ID_HEADER, customTypeId.getBytes());
                            }
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // TODO report error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return super.deserialize(topic, customHeaders != null ? customHeaders : headers, data);
    }
}
```

this enabled us to configure the kafka listener to deserialize incoming classes into any other classes we want.